# Where are Credentials stored for Network Drives on WinXP?

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares

I have a drive mapped to a folder on a remote machine that I connect to using the Cisco VPN client.

The password to the Windows account I use on that remote machine has changed.

I had stored the username/password locally, using Window's remember my password feature, so I wouldn't have to enter it every time (the enter user/password login dialog used to appear each time I attempted to open the remote folder, and I would have to look up and enter my credentials).

The password to that remote Windows account has changed.

Now, I am no longer prompted to enter a user name / password, but instead, upon trying to open the remote folder, receive a message: unknown user name or bad password.

How do I view and change these stored credentials?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open control panel and then User Accounts.  Click Advanced tab and then Manage Passwords.  You should then see a list of the locations that have stored/cached passwords. Delete the one in question and you will be prompted for credentials once again.

Comment: Shortcut: `control keygmr.dll`

Comment: 2grawity: it's actually `control keymgr.dll`, of course.

Alternative shortcut: `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr`